# AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I have a problem that is driving me crazy the last few days. It's about AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer method.
No matter what I do, it always cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this line. I know there're a couple of posts talking about it, but none can help me.

This is my situation: I'm rendering into a texture with OpenGLES and I want to create a video from those textures. Here's my code:

Creating FBO, attached texture and pixelBuffer to fill in render:

```
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_secondFrameBuffer);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_depthRenderBuffer);

CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(NULL, [_videoWriter.pixelBufferInput pixelBufferPool], &_fboTexturePixelBuffer);
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                             _textureCache,
                                             _fboTexturePixelBuffer,
                                             NULL,
                                             GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                             GL_RGBA,
                                             (int)size.width,
                                             (int)size.height,
                                             GL_BGRA,
                                             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                             0,
                                             &_fboTexture);

glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_fboTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_fboTexture));
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, size.width, size.height);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _secondFrameBuffer);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_fboTexture), 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBuffer);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _secondFrameBuffer);
```

AVAssetWriter creation :

```
    _dataQueue = dispatch_queue_create("data_queue", NULL);
    _assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:outputURL fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:nil];

    int width = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    int height = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.height * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                   nil];

    _assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];
    _assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;

    NSDictionary *bufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey,
                                      nil];

    _assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:_assetWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:bufferAttributes];


    [_assetWriter addInput:_assetWriterInput];

    _presentationTime = kCMTimeZero;
    [_assetWriter startWriting];
    [_assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:_presentationTime];
```

And then, I just try to append the pixel Buffer ...

```
- (void)appendPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer
{
dispatch_async(_dataQueue, ^{

    if (pixelBuffer != NULL) {
        [_assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer    withPresentationTime:_presentationTime];
        CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
        _presentationTime = CMTimeAdd(_presentationTime, frameTime);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"NULL PixelBuffer !");
    }
});
}
```

CRASH -> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Can anyone help me PLEASE !?

THANKS !

Comment: Where is `GL_BGRA` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem in method `- (void)appendPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer`. If you use ARC please make sure your pixelBuffer is not release on async queue to make it sure please try this code.

```
- (void)appendPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer
{
   CVPixelBufferRetain(pixelBuffer);
   dispatch_async(_dataQueue, ^{
      if (pixelBuffer != NULL) {
        [_assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer    withPresentationTime:_presentationTime];
        CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
        _presentationTime = CMTimeAdd(_presentationTime, frameTime);
        CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
      } else {
        NSLog(@"NULL PixelBuffer !");
      }
   });
}
```